# In Django, how do I write a this for every function?

Tags: python, django, oop, decorator

Whenever someone loads a page, I want to print "Hello" in console.

I don't want to add a decorator to all my 100 views. That's silly.
I sort of want this decorator to automatically be added to my views.
Hmm...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Middleware: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

Define a middleware class, override one of the functions defined above, print "Hello", return the appropriate object (according to docs), and add the middleware class to your settings.py

```
class PrintHelloMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        print "Hello"
        return None

# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( # ... usual middleware
                       'path.to.my.middleware.PrintHelloMiddleware',
                      )
```

Comment: How would the code look like? Do I put everything in __init__? What are the functions of that class?

Comment: the docs I linked to shows what the functions you can override are and what to return

Comment: How do I make this only available to functions in my views.py (and not media, etc)

Comment: media shouldn't go through this phase because you shouldn't be serving media through a django view!

Comment: But you could potentially override `process_view` which exposes the `view_func` being called. You could do some sketchy `inspect` calls to determine if the file name is `views.py` and only print if so.