# If I set a variable in my middleware, how do I make that available to my views in my views.py?

Tags: python, django, middleware

This is my middleware:

```
class Go():
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        aaa = "hello"
        return None
```

If I go into my views.py and `print aaa`, I get an error.

Comment: Let's just assume you're kidding about this question as written.  Perhaps you could provide some real code to provide a real context for this question.

Comment: It's kind of important, when programming (or stitching together swathes of others' code), to be able to distinguish a local variable from other types of variable.

Comment: @S.Lott: Here's the context -- http://stackoverflow.com/q/4808664/78845

Comment: @Johnsyweb: It's kind of important, when programming (or stitching together swathes of others' code), to be able to make design decisions, write code and do some debugning without posting every single step of the process as a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @S.Lott: One step at a time ;-)

Comment: @Johnsyweb: One step at a time is good.  Actually doing the work oneself is better.

Comment: @S.Lott: I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it available in your views, you can add anything you want to the `request` object as that's ultimately passed down to your views.

```
request.myvar = 'hello'
```

Comment: Is there a way I can just do "myvar" instead of request.myvar?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
request.aaa = "hello"
```

and then in your view:

```
print request.aaa
```