# How to set in a middleware a variable accessible in all my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, middleware

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to use middlewares in order to set a variable `@variable_name` accessible later in controllers.

For example my middleware is

```
  class Auth

    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      @account ||= Account.find(1)

      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
```

The above code set properly the `@account` variable, but that isn't available in my application (in controllers, models, views, ...). So, **how can I accomplish that?**

---

I seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808925/if-i-set-a-variable-in-my-middleware-how-do-i-make-that-available-to-my-views-in) that is a way to do what I need, but I would like to have the `@account` variable "directly accessible". That is, without use that way but making that available, for example in my views, like this:

```
<%= debug @account %>
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done in the Middleware. Did you try it in the `ApplicationController` with `before_filter :set_my_var`?

Comment: @Wukerplank I need that in a middleware.

Comment: You could try something dirty and possible harmful like storing it in `Thread.current[:my_var] = Account.find(1)`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use 'env' for that. So in your middleware you do this:

```
def call(env)
  env['account'] = Account.find(1)
  @app.call(env)
end
```

You can get the value by using 'request' in your app:

```
request.env['account']
```

And please don't use global variables or class attributes as some people suggest here. That's a sure way to get yourself into troubles and really is a bad habit.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. After your answer I instantly remembered the omniauth and it use the same practice. Also I noticed that you can do the same thing from the routes constraint (it's especially helpful to low down number of requests to the database in my case)... you can pass any value to the request.env and catch it inside the action or controller.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this can be done with a Middelware. My suggestion would be this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :set_my_var

private
  def set_my_var
    @account ||= Account.find(1)
  end

end
```

This way all your controllers and views have access to `@account`

Comment: A problem with this approach is when you are calculating something in the middleware itself for assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5.2 added [ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html#method-i-reset) for this kind of globally relevant request context data.  You inherit from it to create a singleton class accessible from anywhere, which is automatically reset between requests.  So now you can do something like:

```rb
class RequestContext < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :account
end
```

and then...

```rb
class Auth
  ...
  def call(env)
    RequestContext.account ||= Account.find(1)

    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

I've never used it from a middleware - you may have to experiment with when the CurrentAttributes instance gets reset for each request (somewhere in the middleware stack? after the middleware stack?)

Answer (score -4):

You can have a cattr_accessor :my_var in any model and set this variable from middleware by

```
  MyModel.my_var = 'something'
```

And you can access this anywhere in the application.

Comment: I didn't understand well. Can you make a real example, please?

Comment: add "cattr_accessor :my_var" somewhere in the model file. This creates a setter and getter for MyModel.my_var: http://pastie.org/2345283

Comment: Not thread safe, and even not the answer on the main question, how to pass variable from middleware to a controller actions.

Answer (score -6):

Have you tried creating a Ruby global variable?

```
def call(env)
  $account ||= Account.find(1)

  @app.call(env)
end
```

and

```
<%= debug $account %>
```

Comment: In 100 out of 100 cases, global variables are not the answer.