# Multi tenant web app: Devise inside Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, multi-tenant

I'm trying to build a multi tenant app, where a user can have their own website, and within that websites, visitors can create accounts and login etc.

I'll be using Postgresql schemas for this app.

Now a user can create a basic website, add content etc. But I want visitors to be able to register for an account in those websites.

For example, a user create the website site.app.com
He can login to site.app.com/admin to manage his website.
Now I want visitors to be able to create an account in site.app.com (of course the account will be stored and that website's schema), login and logout etc.

This is getting confused and if someone has ever done something like this please help me achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've done something like it before.

I need to explain it...

`Multi Tenancy` in the standard sense denotes the use of multiple environments for a single application. As [explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy):

> Software Multitenancy refers to a software architecture in **which a
>   single instance of a software runs on a server and serves multiple
>   tenants**. A tenant is a group of users who share a common access with
>   specific privileges to the **software instance**. With a multitenant
>   architecture, a software application is designed to provide every
>   tenant a dedicated share of the instance including its data,
>   configuration, user management, tenant individual functionality and
>   non-functional properties. Multitenancy contrasts with multi-instance
>   architectures, where separate software instances operate on behalf of
>   different tenants.

In short, this means that a truly multi tenant application should be able to serve a number of different users with the same resources. In terms of Rails, this is pretty simple because it's all built on HTTP - a [*stateless* protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol).

*Real* "cloud" applications (which we're yet to see) would have to be *stateful* - much like a native application harnessing the computing power of a datacenter. A good example would be one of those RPG games which keep all your data stored on their server.

--

Although Rails is naturally multi-tenant, its database is not.

[How to create a multi-tenant database with shared table structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213006/how-to-create-a-multi-tenant-database-with-shared-table-structures)

In my head - and maybe I'm "wrong" - a real multi tenant app should allocate a separate data-base for each user, sharing a central repository of data such as "accounts" etc:

```
-- database
  -- accounts
  -- invoices
  -- users
   -- 1
     -- pictures
     -- users
     -- etc
   -- 2
     -- pictures
     -- users
     -- etc
```

This might seem complicated, but if you treat it properly, it will give you the ability to store the data for each user securely etc.

---

In regards your application, it means that you're going to be storing all your data in a *single* db, linked to a *single* app.

This means that your user authentication structure can be created with `sessions` and `roles`:

- Each "subdomain" stores sessions for that subdomain *only*
- Each "subdomain" (account) validates against users assigned to that account
- Each user will have roles assigned to their participation in said account

Simple implementation of the models:

```
#app/models/account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   # This is for the "site" -- will create the subdomain etc
   has_many :memberships
   has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

#app/models/membership.rb
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :role
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :memberships
   has_many :accounts, thorugh: :memberships
end

#app/models/role.rb
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :memberships
end
```

This will allow you to create *accounts*, assign *users* to those accounts, and store different information in the *membership* model (such as role etc).

--

This will give you the primary functionality of a multi-tenant application (the ability to have "accounts", customize the environment for those accounts, and then have members for that specific account).

There are various other things you can do, but the main after that is the *sessions* (so a user can only log in to a single subdomain):

[Share session (cookies) between subdomains in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails)

This is handled by default; if you wanted to "share" sessions between subdomains, you'd have to add `tld_length: 2` to your `session_store.rb`

--

To handle the subdomains, [just set it up in the routes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) (like how Ryan Bates did it with his Railscast):

```
#config/routes.rb
scope constraints: AccountManager do

    #This is from an app we're working on..... put what you want here.

    #Users
    devise_for :users, path: "", controllers: { sessions: "auth/sessions" }, path_names: { sign_in: "login", password: "forgot", confirmation: "confirm", unlock: "unblock", sign_up: "", invitation: "add", accept: "", registration: "register", sign_out: "logout" }

    #Authentication
    authenticate :user do
      root "transactions#index", as: :authenticated
    end

    #Core
    authenticated :user do
      resource  :settings, controller: :users, only: [:show, :update], constraints: { format: :js }         # User profile & settings (doubles up as options editor)
      resources :transactions, path: "", only: [:index, :update, :destroy], constraints: { format: :js } do # CRUD transactions
        scope format: true do #-> for constraints
          get :new, on: :new, constraints: { format: :js }
        end
        match "search(/:query)", action: :search, as: :search, on: :collection, via: [:get, :post]
      end
    end

end

#lib/account_manager.rb
module AccountManager

    # Refs
    # https://viget.com/extend/using-routing-constraints-to-root-your-app
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192175/how-to-set-in-a-middleware-a-variable-accessible-in-all-my-application

    def initializer(router)
        @router = router
    end

    def self.matches?(request)
        Account.exists? request.subdomain
    end

end
```

This will allow you to sign in etc (you'll have to modify Devise to accept only `members` of the account).

---

Finally, to get the "admin" section working, you'll be best creating an "/admin" path in your subdomain, allowing only admin roles access:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope constraint: AccountManager do
   namespace :admin do #-> account.app.com/admin
      # stuff here
   end
end
```

This would allow you to use basic authorization in the admin controllers:

```
#app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb
class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :is_admin?

   private

   def is_admin?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Admin Only" unless current_user.admin? #-> has to check membership if is admin
   end
end
```

You could also make a separate admin interface on app.com/admins or something; where you could only let admins sign in etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this.  If you are using schemas and switching the scope of the app when someone visits a particular page or is logged into a specific context, then that should be all you need to do.

Most people will accomplish this by just adding a model above the users (like Account), then when you create the account when someone freshly signs up to your site and then associate the users with the account_id as a foreign key.  After that you scope the activity in your app to the proper account and everything else works the same.  Here is how you do that with devise.  Here is an example of how you can do this in devise in the RegistrationsController.

http://www.austinstory.com/category/programming/rubyonrails/devise/